# Cannot assign a value to a Computed column in Lighswitch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, calculated-columns

I have a table in Lightswitch to which I have added a computed column named 'FullName'. In the method for that field..I have written
FullName = this.EmployeeFirstName + " " + this.EmployeeMiddleName + " " + this.EmployeeLastName;

but C# is giving me an error 'Property or Indexer  cannot be assigned to -- it is read only'

Can anyone please help me with this one??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To set the value of the computed property, you set the value of the "result" parameter that is passed into the FullName_Compute method.

```
partial void FullName_Compute(ref string result)
{
    result = this.EmployeeFirstName + " " + this.EmployeeMiddleName + " " + this.EmployeeLastName;
}
```

[How to: Add a Computed Field in a LightSwitch Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851997.aspx)